# Need a powershell script to read and fetch filenames from a text file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a text file in below format - fileList.txt

```
2017-01-05 13:27:35          0 logs/
2017-01-06 03:08:10        798 logs/Logs_2016-01-06.zip
2017-01-05 14:23:45          0 logs/logs/
2017-01-06 03:08:10        798 logs/Logs_2016-06-06.zip
2017-01-06 03:08:10        798 logs/Logs_2016-04-06.zip
2017-01-06 03:08:10        798 logs/Logs_2016-04-06.zip
2017-01-06 03:08:10        798 logs/Logs_2016-03-06.zip
```

I need a powershell script to fetch all the filename in this file for eg: Logs_2016-03-06.zip which has date substring that of more than 30 days old from current date and remove them in disk.

I hope this question explains my problem.

Comment: Can you show your current script so we can see what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just use some string functions to convert your text into a psobject, use a `New-Timespan` to get the days. Something like this:

```
Get-Content your_file.txt | % {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    days = (New-Timespan -start (Get-Date $_.Substring(0, 19)) -end (Get-Date)).Days
    file = $_ -replace '^.*\s\s\d+\s(.+)$', '$1'
  }
} | ? {$_.file -match '\.' -and $_.days -gt 30} | % {
  Remove-Item $_.file
}
```